# Callback not suppoprted compiling contracts with solc

Tags: solc, solcjs

I'm building a Web-API with express which should compile two Smart Contracts and its imports.
I've tried almost anything but I don't get it to work. I have the error "Callback not supported" (NOT "File import callback not supported"):

```
{"errors":[{"component":"general","errorCode":"6275","formattedMessage":"ParserError: Source \"utils/Context.sol\" not found: Callback not supported.\n --> Contract:5:1:\n  |\n5 | import \"../utils/Context.sol\";\n  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n\n","message":"Source \"utils/Context.sol\" not found: Callback not supported.","severity":"error","sourceLocation":{"end":88,"file":"Contract","start":58},"type":"ParserError"}],"sources":{}}
```

My api code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var output;
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  
      const path = require("path");
      const fs = require("fs-extra");
      const solc = require("solc");

      const MyCoin = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../contracts", "MyCoin.sol"), "utf8");

      const IERC721 = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721", "IERC721.sol"), "utf8");
      const ERC721Holder = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname,"../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/utils","ERC721Holder.sol"), "utf8");
      const IERC721Metadata = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname,"../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions","IERC721Metadata.sol"), "utf8");
      const Address = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname,"../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/utils","Address.sol"), "utf8");
      const Context = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname,"../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/utils","Context.sol"), "utf8");
      const Strings = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname,"../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/utils","Strings.sol"), "utf8");
      const ERC165 = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname,"../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/utils/introspection","ERC165.sol"), "utf8");
      const Ownable = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname,"../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/access","Ownable.sol"), "utf8");
      const Dex = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname,"../contracts","Dex.sol"));
      const ReentrancyGuard = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/security","ReentrancyGuard.sol"), "utf8");
      const IERC165 = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/utils/introspection","IERC165.sol"), "utf8");

      const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "../build");
      fs.removeSync(buildPath);

      function compileContract(Contract) {
        const contractPath = path.resolve(...Contract);  
        
        const contractSourceCode = fs.readFileSync(contractPath, "utf8");
        
        fs.ensureDirSync(buildPath);
    
        var input = {
            language: "Solidity",
            sources: {
              Contract: {
                content: contractSourceCode
              }
                //'MyCoin.sol' : {content : MyCoin},
                //'IERC721.sol' : {content : IERC721},
                //'ERC721Holder.sol' : {content : ERC721Holder},
                //'IERC721Metadata.sol' : {content : IERC721Metadata},
                //'Address.sol' : {content : Address},
                //'Context.sol' : {content : Context},
                //'Strings.sol' : {content : Strings},
                //'ERC165.sol' : {content : ERC165},
                //'Dex.sol' : {content : Dex},
                //'Ownable.sol' : {content : Ownable},
                //'ReentrancyGuard.sol' : {content : ReentrancyGuard},
            },
            settings: {
                optimizer: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                outputSelection: {
                    "*": {
                        "*": [ "*" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    
        function findImports(lpath) {
            if (lpath === path.resolve(__dirname,"../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions","IERC721Metadata.sol")) return { contents: `${IERC721Metadata}` };
            if (lpath === path.resolve(__dirname, "../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721", "IERC721.sol")) return { contents: `${IERC721}` };
            if (lpath === path.resolve(__dirname, "../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/security","ReentrancyGuard.sol")) return { contents: `${ReentrancyGuard}` };
            if (lpath === path.resolve(__dirname,"../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/utils","Address.sol")) return { contents: `${Address}` };
            if (lpath === path.resolve(__dirname,"../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/utils","ERC721Holder.sol")) return { contents: `${ERC721Holder}` };
            if (lpath === path.resolve(__dirname,"../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/utils","Context.sol")) return { contents: `${Context}` };
            if (lpath === path.resolve(__dirname,"../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/utils","Strings.sol")) return { contents: `${Strings}` };
            if (lpath === path.resolve(__dirname,"../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/utils/introspection","ERC165.sol")) return { contents: `${ERC165}` };
            if (lpath === path.resolve(__dirname,"../contracts","Dex.sol")) return { contents: `${Dex}` };
            if (lpath === path.resolve(__dirname, "../contracts", "MyCoin.sol")) return { contents: `${MyCoin}` };
            if (lpath === path.resolve(__dirname,"../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/access","Ownable.sol")) return { contents: `${Ownable}` };
            if (lpath === path.resolve(__dirname, "../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/utils/introspection","IERC165.sol")) return {contents: `${IERC165}`};
            else return {};
          }
    
        output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input), { import: findImports }));

        //for(var contractName in output.contracts.Contract) {
        //    fs.outputJsonSync(
        //        path.resolve(buildPath, `${contractName}.json`),
        //        output.contracts.Contract[contractName]
        //    );
        //}    
    }
    compileContract([__dirname,"../contracts/", "Dex.sol"]);
    compileContract([__dirname,"../contracts/", "MyCoin.sol"]);
    compileContract([__dirname,"../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions", "IERC721Metadata.sol"]);
    compileContract([__dirname,"../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721", "IERC721.sol"]);
    compileContract([__dirname,"../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/security", "ReentrancyGuard.sol"]);
    compileContract([__dirname,"../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/utils", "Address.sol"]);
    compileContract([__dirname,"../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/utils", "ERC721Holder.sol"]);
    compileContract([__dirname,"../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/utils","Context.sol"]);
    compileContract([__dirname,"../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/utils","Strings.sol"]);
    compileContract([__dirname, "../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/utils/introspection","IERC165.sol"]);
    compileContract([__dirname,"../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/utils/introspection","ERC165.sol"]);
    compileContract([__dirname,"../contracts/openzeppelin/contracts/access","Ownable.sol"]);
    res.send(output);
});



module.exports = router;
```

solc version: 0.8.13
express: 4.17.3

I am so thankful for every help!

Comment: I have same problem, but i'm using solc 0.8.14 and pragma 0.8.0

Comment: Well its long ago, but I managed to solve the error. One big mistake was having two Smart Contracts which imported each other, you should use an interface instead which is implemented by one class and instantiated in the other class. Is this your problem too?